# Is there a way to change angular routing component depending on the value of a routing parameter

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, url-parameters

I have the following route with a parameter:

```
RouterModule.forRoot({ path: 'record/:type', component: RecordComponent,
                       children: [{ path: 'edit/:id', component: RecordEditorComponent },
                                  ...] }, ...);
```

Inside the `RecordComponent`, I'm checking the type parameter and use it to set the database url to call and get the type data I need.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._route.paramMap.subscribe((parameters: ParamMap) => this.init(parameters));
  ...
}

private init(parameters: ParamMap): void {
  this.recordType = parameters.get('type')?.toLowerCase() as RecordType | undefined;
  if (!this.recordType) {
    this._router.navigate(['/error', 404]);
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

This works fine. But I now need a specialized `NestedRecordComponent`, which is derived from `RecordComponent`, to be used for one of the types. So I've added the route:

```
RouterModule.forRoot({ path: 'record/species', component: NestedRecordComponent, ... },
                     { path: 'record/:type', component: RecordComponent, ... }, ...)
```

Now, of course, the RecordType (which is just a string enum btw.) in the url can't be found anymore. Is there a way to tell the route that *species* is supposed to be one of the type parameters?

I've also tried to use UrlSegments instead of type parameters, which works fine in the `RecordComponent`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._route.url.subscribe((segments: UrlSegment[]) => this.init(segments));
  ...
}

private init(segments: UrlSegment[]): void {
  this.recordType = segments.at(-1)?.path.toLowerCase() as RecordType | undefined;
  ...
}
```

However, it does not work in the child route, which also requires the type parameter, as well as the id. I've managed to pass the parent's parameters on to the child route by adding `{ paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always' }` to the route definitions but I have not found a way to pass on the parent's url segments, thus I would have to create two subscriptions, one for the child and one for the parent route just to get those two values, which I would really like to avoid.

Currently, the `RecordEditorComponent` does this, with *type*, of course, coming from the parent route:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._route.paramMap.subscribe((parameters: ParamMap) => this.init(parameters));
}

private init(parameters: ParamMap): void {
  this._recordType = parameters.get('type')?.toLowerCase() as RecordType | undefined;
  let recordId: string | null = parameters.get('id');
  ...
}
```

I would love to have something like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot({ path: 'record/:type',
                       if: { param: 'type', value: 'species' },
                       component: NestedRecordComponent, ... },
                     { path: 'record/:type', component: RecordComponent, ... }, ...)
```

Does anything like this exist? Or is there a way to pass on parent url segments to the child route?